# Adding a Unity3d project as dynamic feature module in a native app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I have a unity3d Android project, how can i integrate my unity3d android project as a dynamic feature module in an already existing native android app so that it would be downloaded on demand within the native android app.

Comment: You can't. The close you might be able to get is using the AssetBundle to make the whole game

Comment: @PerformanceFreak can you please tell me why we cannot?. I have exported unity3d project as android studio project. So it is just like another android module. While i am trying to build, it is giving me manifest merge problem.

Comment: You can integrate it in compile time but not dynamically. You can't download Unity game into your Android app during run-time. That must be done in build-time then use Assetbundle to update the game during run-time